# Creating .htaccess hidden redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

How can I make redirect from /katalog/protein/api and /katalog/protein/activelab to katalog/protein/?ms|manufacturer=API and katalog/protein/?ms|manufacturer=ActiveLab.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/katalog/(protein|gainer)/(api|activelab)/?$ /katalog/$1/?ms|manufacturer=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code look fine, just remove the leading slash from RewriteRule's pattern.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^katalog/(protein|gainer)/(api|activelab)/?$ /katalog/$1/?ms|manufacturer=$2 [L,QSA,NE,NC]
```